# How to rotate textView with a float value in iOS7?

Tags: ios, uitextview, cgaffinetransform

I have an application. The last few days I tried to update it for the brand new iOS7 but I think I found a little strange thing (maybe a bug) when I tried the app on my device.

I spent the whole day to find out what could be the problem because under iOS6 is everything goin' OK.

My app using the CGAffineTransformMakeRotation for rotating the textView with its content (some text). If I add a float value (for example: 33.33) for the rotation in iOS6 is still ok (like in the good old times), but in iOS7 the textView's text is going under and out of the textview"s box (especially if the text align is right).

With the code below anybody can test this situation:

```
int textNumber = 1;

UITextView *textView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width/2 - 75, self.view.frame.size.height/2 - 60, 150, 120)];

textView.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
textView.text = @"Valami";
textView.delegate = self;
textView.scrollEnabled = NO;
textView.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
textView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
textView.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDefault;
textView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
textView.editable = NO;
textView.tag = textNumber;
textView.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentRight;

[self.view addSubview:textView];


[UIView beginAnimations:@"rotate" context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDelay: 1.0];
[UIView setAnimationDuration: 3.0];



float res = 13.7657657567;

[self.view viewWithTag:1].transform=CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(res);


[UIView commitAnimations];
```

If anybody know anything about this problem please help me! Thank you!

Comment: block-based animation... where is the proper block-based animation which the Apple recommends on iOS4 or above...?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html

Comment: It's seems to be the right answer is to create a UIView and add the textView as a subview like this:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/9195977/1228695

but I still can't understand why is it workin' perfectly with iOS6 and not with iOS7....